how to add header file into the .xcodeproj
enter image description here
when im trying to add the imported framework into my xcodeproj, i coundn't get to know how to implement with this enter image description here,github:https://github.com/Tencent/MMKV
i have tried to edit in the build phases, but it turns out not working
